# boto3 lambda call to run ECS task requires hardcoding in a revision number?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-ecs

Long story short, I don't want to have to hardcode in ECS task definition revision numbers for tasks into my lambda source codes. It's essentially toil updating my source code each time I have an updated task definition. In [the boto3 documentation for ECS `run_task()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html), it clearly states

> taskDefinition (string) -- [REQUIRED]
>
> The family and revision (family:revision ) or full ARN of the task
>   definition to run. **If a revision is not specified, the latest ACTIVE
>   revision is used**.

However, I am finding that if I define the `taskDefinition` parameter in `client.run_task()` with no specific revision number, I get a permission error:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the RunTask
>   operation: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::MY_ACCOUNT_ID:assumed-role/my-lambda-role/trigger-ecs-task
>   is not authorized to perform: ecs:RunTask on resource:
>   arn:aws:ecs:MY_REGION:MY_ACCOUNT_ID:task-definition/an-important-task

If I switch my definition to `an-important-task:LATEST` or `an-important-task:*`, I get another error:

> ...is not authorized to perform: ecs:RunTask on resource: *

This is strange, because it appears contrary to what the documentation states- when I include a revision number, like `an-important-task:5`, the lambda triggers perfectly. In my lambda function, I simply invoke my ECS task:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('ecs')
    print("Running task.")
    response = client.run_task(
        cluster='my-cluster', 
        launchType='FARGATE',
        taskDefinition='an-important-task',  # <-- notice no revision number
        count=1,
        platformVersion='LATEST',
        networkConfiguration={
            'awsvpcConfiguration': {
                'subnets': [
                    'subnet-1',
                    'subnet-2'
                ],
                'assignPublicIp': 'DISABLED'
            }
        })
    print("Finished invoking task.")
```

In my Terraform definition, I've attached the necessary policies to my role:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "trigger-ecs-task" {
  function_name = "trigger-ecs-task"
  handler = "my-lambda-function.lambda_handler"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.lambda.arn}"
  runtime = "python3.6"
  # other stuff related to how I store my source code for the lambda
}
```

My role definition, and attaching the permissions to run ECS tasks:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda" {
  name = "my-lambda-ecs-role"
  assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.lambda-assume-role.json}"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "lambda-assume-role" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = [
        "lambda.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "run-ecs-policy" {
  name = "run-ecs-task-policy"
  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ecs:RunTask",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ecs:MY_REGION:MY_ACCOUNT_ID:task-definition/an-important-task:*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1512361993201",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::************:role/${data.aws_iam_role.ecs-task-execution-role.name}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

I attach the policy below:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "service-role-attach" {
  role = "${aws_iam_role.lambda.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.run-ecs-policy.arn}"
}
```

Why is AWS refusing to run my task if I don't specify a specific revision?  In my policy definition, I am clearly giving permission to `runTask` on all revisions of the resource:

```
arn:aws:ecs:MY_REGION:MY_ACCOUNT_ID:task-definition/an-important-task:*
```

Comment: Can you try setting `Resource: "*"` for the `iam:PassRole` policy?

Comment: I get the same result. Also, is this only to debug something you think might be causing it? Why would I want to set it to `*` anyways? Isn't that violating the principle of least permissions?

Comment: Yes it is, but if it did work, at least you'd know where the issue is. Too bad it didn't.

Comment: did you try with `client.run_task()` with latest `ACTIVE` as revision? any progresses?

Comment: @BMW I tried running with `an-important-task:LATEST`. You mean try w/ `an-important-task:ACTIVE`?

Comment: Try `an-important-task:$LATEST` (A dollar in it)

Answer (score 14):

I was able to replicate your behavior and resolved the issue with following `Resource` in IAM Policy.

```
{
    "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "ecs:RunTask",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:ecs:MY_REGION:MY_ACCOUNT_ID:task-definition/an-important-task"
}
```

If you are planning to provide with revision then the resource should have `:*` in it or it has to exactly exactly match with `taskDefinition`.

Let me know how it goes at your end!!.