# AWS ECS run_task always throws InvalidParameterException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs

Trying to run a container ECS `FARGARE` or `EC2` using a Lambda function, The trigger is a `PUT` event when a file is uploaded to S3.

The console shows that that task definition is ACTIVE and querying using `client.describe_task_definition` returns the revision I am expecting and it's status is ACTIVE as well, however, calling `run_task()`:

```
response = client.run_task(
    cluster='ec2-cluster',
    taskDefinition='SATWorkers:2',
    launchType = 'EC2',
    count=1,
    networkConfiguration={
        ...
    }
)
```

Always throws `InvalidParameterException` with the message:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the RunTask operation:
TaskDefinition is inactive
```

I tried creating a new cluster with a new task definition, I created multiple revisions and I keep getting the same result.

Comment: Is your revision number 2 is active? Not latest.

Comment: @Lamanus yes it is, `describe_task_definition` returns revision 2 as active

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54281442/boto3-lambda-call-to-run-ecs-task-requires-hardcoding-in-a-revision-number).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [boto3 lambda call to run ECS task requires hardcoding in a revision number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54281442/boto3-lambda-call-to-run-ecs-task-requires-hardcoding-in-a-revision-number)